# Can i have the multi layout orientation for a layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I am having a dynamic layout and am adding the components in a linear layout. The number of components is also dynamic.

When the linear layout orientation is horizontal the items are added horizontally and when  vertical items are added vertically.

Now can i have the tiling of items firstly horizontally and then vertically like when the items are filled up vertically.

Or can i use any other layout for satisfying my need.

Like this[image]

Comment: hi! u can use layout-land for new xml file...u can read about how android offers this at here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Comment: u can use layout-land for new xml file...u can read about how android offers this at here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely have nested `LinearLayout` elements with multiple orientations. For example:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/firstRow"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        ...
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/secondRow"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        ...
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/thirdRow"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        ...
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Using a structure like this will allow you to build the layout you described.

For dynamic rows you can do the following:

**layout_row.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" />
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);

// for each dynamic row you can inflate a new view and add it
dynamicRow1 = getLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_row, null);
mainLayout.addView(dynamicRow1);

dynamicRow2 = getLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_row, null);
mainLayout.addView(dynamicRow2);

dynamicRow3 = getLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_row, null);
mainLayout.addView(dynamicRow3);
```

In each row you can programmatically add the dynamic views that you need to create using the same type of logic.

Comment: My layout is going to be dynamic. so i cannot define the number of rows in advance.

Comment: Thats fair. You could just as easily create a layout file that has just a horizontally oriented `LinearLayout`, inflate that layout programmatically and then add it as a child of the main `LinearLayout`. See the edit for a code sample.